# Swift 4 - Decoding --> [Orders.CodingKeys]' does not conform to expected type 'CodingKey'

Tags: swift, decode

I've been trying to decode a json with custom decoding but i am running into a problem that i haven't been able to solve and I am running out of idea. I commented out the additionalInfo in the Order struct on purpose just to make my life easier.

Any help would be appreciated.

JSON:

```
{"FirstName": "John",
 "LastName": "Smith",
 "Orders":[
  {"Order": {"OrderNumber": "10", "Description": "AAA Battery", "Quantity": "5"}, "AdditionalInfo":[{"Status": "Out for delivery", "Date": "1/3/2018"}, {"Status": "Arrived Vermont CA", "Date": "1/2/2018"}]},
  {"Order": {"OrderNumber": "9", "Description": "Force1 Drone", "Quantity": "1"}, "AdditionalInfo":[{"Status": "Delivered", "Date": "12/25/2017"}, {"Status": "Arrived Vermont CA", "Date": "12/24/2017"}]}]}

CODE:

struct Person: Decodable {
 let firstName: String
 let lastName: String
 let orders: [Orders]

 enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  case firstName = "FirstName"
  case lastName = "LastName"
  case orders = "Orders"
 }
}

extension Person {
 init(from decoder: Decoder) throws { 
  let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Person.CodingKeys.self)
  firstName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .firstName)
  lastName = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .lastName)

  let orderContainer = try values.nestedContainer(keyedBy: [Orders.CodingKeys].self, forKey: .orders)
 }
}

struct Orders: Decodable {
 let order: Order
 //let additionalInfo: [AdditionalInfo]

 enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  case order = "Order"
  //case additionalInfo = "AdditionalInfo"
 }
}

struct Order: Decodable {
 let number: Int16
 let description: String
 let quantity: Int16

 enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
  case number = "OrderNumber"
  case description = "Description"
  case quantity = "Quantity"
 }
}
```

Comment: As a general rule, don't try to implement the decoding logic for a given type within the decoding logic of another type. In your case, it looks like you want custom decoding for `Order` – that's where you should be implementing a custom `init(from:)`. You'll want to get a keyed container and decode a `String` for each of the keys, then converting those that are expected to be `Int16`s.

Comment: BTW, are you stuck with this weird JSON structure where `Orders` is an array of a dictionaries that each have only key, `Order`. This seems like some unnecessary nesting of structures. You've introduced an unnecessary entity in your model...

Comment: @Rob There's actually also an `"AdditionalInfo"` key which OP is currently not decoding.

Comment: Ah, yes. I didn't see that. I just hate seeing the same conceptual name used at multiple levels. I also find it exceedingly confusing to have an `Orders` entity that represents a single `Order` plus shipping `AdditionalInfo`.

Comment: Rob: It's just something i put together since we don't really post data on the web because it's confidential. And that format is the same as what I get from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the reference to `[Orders.CodingKeys].self`. I think you may have intended `[Orders].self`. But that `init(from:)` is not necessary. You can do:

```
struct Person: Decodable {
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String
    let orders: [PurchaseTransaction]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case firstName = "FirstName"
        case lastName = "LastName"
        case orders = "Orders"
    }
}

struct PurchaseTransaction: Decodable {
    let order: Order
    let additionalInfo: [AdditionalInfo]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case order = "Order"
        case additionalInfo = "AdditionalInfo"
    }
}

struct Order: Decodable {
    let number: String
    let description: String
    let quantity: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case number = "OrderNumber"
        case description = "Description"
        case quantity = "Quantity"
    }
}

struct AdditionalInfo: Decodable {
    let status: String
    let date: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case status = "Status"
        case date = "Date"
    }
}
```

Or, if you want `number` and `quantity` of `Order` to be `Int`, that's where you do need an `init(from:)`, to manually convert the strings to integers:

```
struct Order: Decodable {
    let number: Int
    let description: String
    let quantity: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case number = "OrderNumber"
        case description = "Description"
        case quantity = "Quantity"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        guard let number = try Int(values.decode(String.self, forKey: .number)) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [CodingKeys.number], debugDescription: "Expecting string representation of Int"))
        }
        self.number = number

        guard let quantity = try Int(values.decode(String.self, forKey: .quantity)) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(.init(codingPath: [CodingKeys.quantity], debugDescription: "Expecting string representation of Int"))
        }
        self.quantity = quantity

        description = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .quantity)
    }
}
```

---

Note, I renamed your `Orders` entity to be a `PurchaseTransaction` which includes the original `Order` and the `AdditionalInfo`. Whether that's the right name or not is debatable, but I just found it exceedingly confusing to have an entity called `Orders` which represented a single order and its shipping "additional info". But call it whatever you want.

---

Note, if you want to make the `date` property of `AdditionalInfo` to be a `Date`, you'd have to specify a formatter to decode it:

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy"
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(formatter)

let result = try decoder.decode(Person.self, from: data)
```

Comment: I didn't think that I would get a response this quick :) ... thank you, I will try to implement what you posted.

Comment: Rob, actually I got it to work before without using the extension and init stuff. I got stuck with the date format. I was trying to figure out and followed samples online, which brought me to extension stuff :) This is my first iOS project with swift and i'm clueless. Thanks for your sample as well as the date format; however, I was unable to get the date to show.
my property date: String
with the date formatter, i get this value: Date(1176966000000) which is the same as the one returns from the API

if my date: Date then i get error: Date string does not match format expected by formatter

Comment: Okay, I found it. It's Microsoft JSON date format. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, when I created the sample above I forgot that I had issue with the date. I found a sample on how to parse that Microsoft JSON date time from another thread.  Thank you again for your time. Now I can move on to my next screen.